# Is the XCode project name same as the sqlite store for CoreData?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I need to get the database store name for my CoreData and just wanted to know if the name has got anything to do with the Xcode project name.

Comment: It's whatever you set it to, check the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check AppDelegate. It will be in the code that creates the database store.

```
NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"whateveryouwant.sqlite"];
```